# Relace emotion html tags with emotion names using Python

Tags: python, regex, image, emotion

In the html files, it's common to find that people insert emotion marks. Usually, it looks like this:

```
<img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/smile.png" title="Smile"/>
```

If there is only one such emotion img, it's convenient to replace them with its emotion title. For example:

```
def remove_single_img_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<img.*?/>')
    img = re.findall(p, data)
    emotion = img[0].split('title=')[1].split('/')[0]
    return p.sub(emotion, data) 

test1 = u'I love you.<img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/smile.png" title="Smile"/>.I hate bad men.'

remove_single_img_tags(test1)
```

However, if there are multiple emotion marks in the form of img html tags. It's not so easy.

```
def remove_img_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<img.*?/>')
    img = re.findall(p, data)
    emotions = ()
    for i in img:
        emotion = i.split('title=')[1].split('/')[0]
        emotions[i] = emotion
    return p.sub(emotions, data)

test2 = u'I love you<img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/smile.png" title="Smile"/>I hate bad men <img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/mad.png" title="Mad"/>'

remove_img_tags(test2)
```

The python script above does not work. `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `>>> help(re.sub)`:

```
Help on function sub in module re:

sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
    Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
    non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
    replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
    if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
    a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    a replacement string to be used.
```

You can supply a callable for the replacement text that takes the match as an argument and returns the replacement text.

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'<img.*?/>')
# repeat test string 5 times as input data
>>> data = '<img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/smile.png" title="Smile"/>' * 5
>>> p.sub(lambda match: match.group().split('title=')[1].split('/')[0], data)
'"Smile""Smile""Smile""Smile""Smile"'
```

**EDIT** here are the other examples:

```
>>> test1 = u'I love you.<img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/smile.png" title="Smile"/>.I hate bad men.'   >>>
>>> p.sub(lambda match: match.group().split('title=')[1].split('/')[0], test1)
u'I love you."Smile".I hate bad men.'
>>> test2 = u'I love you<img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/smile.png" title="Smile"/>I hate bad men <img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/mad.png" title="Mad"/>'
>>> p.sub(lambda match: match.group().split('title=')[1].split('/')[0], test2)
u'I love you"Smile"I hate bad men "Mad"'
```

I would also suggest adding the title match to your regex, so that you can extract it by group index:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'<img.*?title=(".*?")/>')
>>> p.sub(lambda match: match.group(1), test2)
u'I love you"Smile"I hate bad men "Mad"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
emotions = ()
```

If you change that to

```
emotions = []
```

And then change

```
emotions[i] = emotion
```

To

```
emotions.append(emotion)
```

And then, change

```
return p.sub(emotions, data)
```

To
    return p.sub(tuple(emotions), data)

Then everything will work fine.

Here is your updated code:

```
def remove_img_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<img.*?/>')
    img = re.findall(p, data)
    emotions = []
    for i in img:
        emotion = i.split('title=')[1].split('/')[0]
        emotions.append(emotion)
    return p.sub(tuple(emotions), data)

test2 = u'I love you<img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/smile.png" title="Smile"/>I hate bad men <img alt="" border="0" class="inlineimg" src="images/smilies/mad.png" title="Mad"/>'

remove_img_tags(test2)
```

---

```
>>> x = ()
>>> x[0] = 'hello'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> x = []
>>> x.append('hello')
>>> x
['hello']
>>>
```

Comment: Actually I have also tried that before. However, it does not work. TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: The result is still not quite right. It should be u'I love you"Smile"I hate bad men "Mad"'